# Inserting into table using data from two other tables, using PL/SQL on SQLDeveloper

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm writing a PL/SQL procedure, and I need to insert into a Table, based on an equality of two columns from two differents tables.

Here is my code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE insertSomething
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO MYDBP ( ZIP )
  SELECT POSTCODE
  FROM ZIPDBP
  WHERE ZIPDBP.ZIP = OTHERDBP.ZIP;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

I'm getting an error saying OTHERDBP.ZIP is an invalid identifier. What is the issue?

EDIT:

To get the output I expected I need another equality statement between two of the tables ID, but again I'm getting invalid identifier again, this time for DBP_CLIENTS.ID. Here is the code

```
INSERT INTO DBP_CLIENTS ( POSTCODE )
SELECT POSTCODE
FROM DBP_POSTCODE, HELENS_DATA
WHERE DBP_POSTCODE.LOCALITY = HELENS_DATA.SUBURB
AND DBP_POSTCODE.STATE = 'NSW'
AND DBP_CLIENTS.ID = HELENS_DATA.ID;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: try add `DBP_CLIENTS` to `from`

Comment: you must indicate from which table `postcode` you want to use

Comment: Yeah I changed but still no go, damn. The things is, I need to add this column data to rows that already exist, based on the ID equality statement, but it keeps adding to new rows.

Comment: `insert into` inserts new row - you need `update` - see here: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/update.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE insertSomething
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MYDBP ( ZIP )
        SELECT POSTCODE
    FROM ZIPDBP, OTHERDBP
    WHERE ZIPDBP.ZIP = OTHERDBP.ZIP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

You have to add otherdbp to `from` section. And you don't need to use `()` in procedure declaration.
Moreover, `insert` is reserverd word in pl/sql, so procedure must have different name

Comment: The code ran but the output wasn't what I expected. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add DBP_CLIENTS in the FROM clause:

```
 INSERT INTO DBP_CLIENTS ( POSTCODE )
 SELECT POSTCODE
 FROM DBP_POSTCODE, HELENS_DATA, DBP_CLIENTS
  WHERE DBP_POSTCODE.LOCALITY = HELENS_DATA.SUBURB
  AND DBP_CLIENTS.ID = HELENS_DATA.ID
  AND DBP_POSTCODE.STATE = 'NSW';
 COMMIT;
```